# How to log every query in solr using slow query log?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, full-text-search

I have been using elasticsearch and in that you just set the slowquerylog threshold to 0 and all queries would be logged so I tried the same in solr.

I am using the techproducts example here and just added the following config to the file 
**/home/ygrover/software/solr-8.3.1/server/solr/configsets/sample_techproducts_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml**

```
<slowQueryThresholdMillis>0</slowQueryThresholdMillis>
```

also I changed the logging level in solr via the http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~logging/level to ALL

**The log folder is at the location /home/ygrover/software/solr-8.3.1/server/logs**
but there are no logs printing in the file **solr_slow_requests.log**

Am I missing something here.

Note : I am doing this for testing and local env only. also if there is an alternative way then please suggest but I need to know what is the missing peice here as this process works seamlessly in elasticsearch.

Edit 1 :

Facing this problem in cloud mode only when launching the techproducts example: followed this tutorial : https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/solr-tutorial.html

I have edited the _default config as well and set the slow query thrshold to 0 there as well. This config works when I dont run in cloud mode and I can then see all queries logged in the solr_slow_requests.log

Comment: As long as you have logging set to at least INFO, all queries should be logged to the regular log

Comment: There are no queries getting logged at the moment and there is a different file also for the same, In elasticsearch the queries get logged to slowlog file and I could see a slow_request file here also so it should have been logged there, and I have set the logging level via the dashboard to all so all kinds of logs would be written for solr

Comment: When you're running in cloud mode, the config is stored inside zookeeper and is not read from disk. If you're only changing the value on disk, that change is not reflected inside Solr. You [can use zkCli](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/command-line-utilities.html) with the `downconfig` and `upconfig` to download or upload configuration files from Zookeeper.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh, this is what was missing